# Manipulate the Style Display property

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style> 
         #myDIV {
         width: 500px;
         height: 500px;
         background-color: lightblue;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element to "none":</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <div id="myDIV">
         This is my DIV element.
      </div>
      <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm working with style display property. How can i manipulate the code, so that at the beginning the DIV element is hidden and when i click the button it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Javascript function:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
}
```

And CSS:

```
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
```

So basically `#myDIV` will not be displayed at first. When the button is clicked, `myFunction()` is run, changing `#myDIV`'s display to block, which is the default display for `div`s.

Comment: Thank you my friend, i'll accept the answer in a couple of minutes (time restriction).. Just one more thing. Can this property be used for an image slider?

Comment: @randy What do you mean by "an image slider"? What is the code for the image slider?

Comment: i still don't have a code for the image slider.. I'm trying to build but not being successful. How can i show it to you (i have an image) ?

Comment: @randy I think it should still work, just that you need to change the `display` accordingly, for the Javascript function, depending on the element that is being shown.

Comment: Can i show you the image? Maybe you'll give me an insight on how to do it?

Comment: i created it as a question before but all i've got was negative feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80236/discussion-between-randy-and-chris97ong).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `display:none` on the div initially. and the javascript code you have should work, except change none to `block`

Answer (score 0):

You must add style of the div to **display : none;**.

Then you need to change the display when the button triggers.

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
```

Try this code if works now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style> 
         #myDIV {
         width: 500px;
         height: 500px;
         background-color: lightblue;
         display:none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element to "none":</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <div id="myDIV">
         This is my DIV element.
      </div>
      <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```